# Who is Vasudev Krishna and who is Yashodanandan Krishna?

Tags: krishna, vaishnavism, bhagavata-purana, gaudiya-vaishnavism, iskcon

I have heard many Acharyas and saints mentioning Vasudev Krishna and Yashodanandan Krishna to be different. Is there any scriptural reference to it? If yes, what is the difference between the two? Who was on the battlefield of Kurukshetra and who in Dwarka? Who had 16108 queens?

Comment: Kṛṣṇa was the biological son of Vasudeva, so he has the patronym Vāsudeva. He is called Yaśodānandana, after his foster mother Yaśodā. One of the meanings of ‘nandana’ is son